# Joda Time - Get name of time zone?

Tags: java, jodatime

My time zone is UTC+03:00. It is stored inside a DateTimeZone object. How do I convert this to its real name, that is, [East Africa Time/EAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC+03:00)

Comment: Is there nothing useful in the documentation? http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html

Comment: @FoolishSeth - used getName() and getID() of DateTimeZone. Trying  getNameProvider() now.

Comment: bookmarking a related  link - http://www.dxing.com/utcgmt.htm

Comment: what arguments do i put into this - String getShortName(Locale locale,
                    String id,
                    String nameKey) ?

Comment: Read the answer to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718484/how-to-print-out-time-zone-abbreviations-when-using-offset-hours-in-joda-time?rq=1. One offset can have multiple real names asociated with it.

Answer (score 11):

With joda, one can get Time-zone abbreviation or name as below

```
DateTimeZone dz = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");
String tzid = dz.getShortName(DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis());
//tzid will be 'EST'

String longerTimeZoneName = dz.getName(DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis());
//longerTimeZoneName  will be 'Eastern Standard Time'
```

Comment: herein above answer tzid is not giving the result as you mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

Use method [TimeZone#getDisplayName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDisplayName%28%29)

```
DateTimeZone tz = //...  
tz.toTimeZone().getDisplayName();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to find anything in JodaTime to give the nice readable name.  In my experience, the DateTimeZone.getName() returns the id instead of a more useful name.  So I can only get "America/New_York", not "Eastern Standard Time".

And the suggest of TimeZone.getDisplayName seems to assume you are using TimeZone from Java, not Joda.  I see no getDisplayName() for JodaTime.