# Lowercase z in date time format is returning offset, not abbreviation

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime, datetime-format

I'm stumped. I must admit that I might not be looking in the right place for this bug. That said...

We use `dd MMM YYY HH:mm:ss z` for the date format string. That lowercase `z` should return a three letter abbreviation for the zone, like `PST` or `CET`. And it does. Everywhere but production. On production we get the offset, like `-08:00`. We verified, via the WAR, that we're using joda 2.9.2 everywhere.

We use `dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(timezone)).toString(dateFormat, locale)` where `dateTime` is a `DateTime`, `timezone` is a `String` (verified to be the same across instances, `America/Los_Angeles`). `dateFormat` is, as above, `dd MMM YYY HH:mm:ss z` and `locale` is verified to be `en` across instances.

I noticed this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718484/how-to-print-out-time-zone-abbreviations-when-using-offset-hours-in-joda-time) which brings up the idea that the locale information is getting lost, leaving only the offset. Still, I can't reproduce that regardless of what I use for `timezone` and `locale`. And, of course, we don't use `forOffsetHours`.

*Edit: for what it's worth, I don't think it's the locale because I can use made up values for locale in the `.toString(dateFormat, locale)` like `new Locale("hasdf")` and the date formats as expected. The only way I can get that exact unexpected format is if I use an uppercase `Z` in place of that lowercase `z`.*

*Second Edit: oh, the JVM is the same everywhere.*

Comment: Which specific time zone is giving back an offset?  Are you aware that TZDB started removing "invented" abbreviations for many time zones quite some time ago?

Comment: all timezones give offsets instead of abbreviations.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is related to the locale data in your JVM (check your versions just to make sure they're all the same in all environments).

Anyway, there's a workaround to overwrite the text that Joda uses for timezones names. You need to extend `org.joda.time.tz.DefaultNameProvider`:

```
public class MyNameProvider extends DefaultNameProvider {

    @Override
    public String getShortName(Locale locale, String id, String nameKey, boolean standardTime) {
        if (Locale.ENGLISH.equals(locale) && "America/Los_Angeles".equals(id)) {
            // return the correct name for Daylight Saving Time
            return standardTime ? "PST" : "PDT";
        }

        return super.getShortName(locale, id, nameKey, standardTime);
    }
}
```

Then you do:

```
DateTimeZone.setNameProvider(new MyNameProvider());

DateTime d = new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles"));
System.out.println(d.toString("dd MMM YYY HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH));
```

This will overwrite whatever data the JVM is using and always use "PST" and "PDT" for America/Los_Angeles in English locale.

Comment: yep, double checked - same JVM eeeeeverywhere O.o

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this problem, but I think that Joda gets this info from the JVM itself.

You can check what data Joda is using with this code:

```
String[][] zoneStringsEn = DateTimeUtils.getDateFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH).getZoneStrings();
for (String[] strings : zoneStringsEn) {
    if (strings != null && strings.length >= 5 && "America/Los_Angeles".equals(strings[0])) {
        System.out.println(strings[2]); // "PST" in my JVM
    }
}
```

Probably the environment that doesn't work has a different JVM version.

Comment: double checked - same JVM eeeeeverywhere -_-

Answer (score 0):

> *The only way I can get that exact unexpected format is if I use an uppercase Z in place of that lowercase z*

Well, that's because one uppercase Z gives you the offset, as stated in the javadoc: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

> Zone: **'Z' outputs offset without a colon**, 'ZZ' outputs the offset with a colon, 'ZZZ' or more outputs the zone id.

And lowercase z gives you the zone name:

```
Symbol  Meaning               Presentation   Examples
------  -------               ------------   -------
z       time zone             text           Pacific Standard Time; PST
Z       time zone offset/id   zone           -0800; -08:00; America/Los_Angeles
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance it's some classpath issue.

In our project, we were able to reproduce this problem including JodaTime 2.9.2 and 2.4 both on the classpath.

We were not aware we include old 2.4 version. It wasn't showing in the dependency tree. Eventually, we found joda classes in some old fat JAR dependency we actually no longer needed.

Bear in mind, classpath issues might be non-deterministic between environments.